# Kaspersky blocks internet

Tags: internet, blocking, kaspersky

Hey, I downloaded the new Kaspersky Internet Security 2010, and since then my internet has not been working. As soon as I disable Kaspersky my internet works.

I have narrowed down to what the problem within Kaspersky is and I am currently running it with:

Enabled - File Anti-Virus

Disabled - Mail Anti-Virus

Disabled - Web Anti-Virus

Disabled - IM Anti-Virus

Enabled - Application Control

Enabled - Firewall

Enabled - Protective Defence

Enabled - Network Attack Blocker

Disabled - Anti-Spam

Disabled - Anti-Banner

Disabled - Parental Control

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you managed to get another anti-virus running? I made the mistake once of having both AVG and Avast running at the same time and couldn't get any browser to work.

As soon as I disabled one of them it all worked again.

Comment: This was the problem! Thanks! Turns out I cannot have Avira web guard and the rest of the features of Kaspersky active

Answer (score 2):

You need to check Kaspersky Rules for the firewall. See if all the connections are restricted. See this for details : http://support.kaspersky.com/kis2010/firewall?qid=208280574

Comment: Nah this doesn't seem to be the problem, even when I disable the firewall it is still blocking my internet, I have to pause the protection for the internet to work :/

Comment: It's definitely got to do something with the rules. Lets see if I can find something else.

Comment: Iv updated the description, please look.

Comment: PLease check if KIS has proxy server on and if any invalid proxy is set there.. Go to settings, then
http://i50.tinypic.com/mts8sk.jpg

Comment: The proxy was on but disabling it didn't make a difference, I have found the problem, for some reason I cannot have Avira WebGuard enabled aswell as the other features on Kaspersky, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Thats a very good(read Bad) mistake.. ^_^ Anyway, good that its solved.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/)? It's free and the best protection currently available.

Comment: I doubt that...

Answer (score 1):

After installing Pure 3.0, my laptop wouldn't recognize my home wifi.  I went into settings, firewall.  My home wifi was listed as a public network.

With the dropdown menu, I changed it from `public` network to `trusted` network, then restarted the computer.
My wifi works now.